# Pytest/Locust: ModuleNotFoundError No module named

Tags: python, pytest, performance-testing, locust, web-api-testing

Ive tried to find anwsers on similar topics, but... nothing helped.
When I run my regular tests with `pytest -m blablabla` - there are no problems, but
when I run locust by command:

> locust -f my_locustfiles/instr_performance.py

than got this:

```
(venv) evgen@TLL amapitest % locust -f my_locustfiles/instr_performance.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evgen/venv/bin/locust", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/evgen/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 70, in main
    docstring, _user_classes, shape_class = load_locustfile(_locustfile)
  File "/Users/evgen/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/util/load_locustfile.py", line 58, in load_locustfile
    imported = source.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/evgen/PycharmProjects/api-testing/amapitest/my_locustfiles/instr_performance.py", line 8, in <module>
    from amapitest.src.helpers.jwt_generator import generate_json_web_token
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amapitest.src.helpers'
```

**my project structure:**

```
├── amapitest  
│   ├── my_locustfiles  
│   │   ├── __init__.py  
│   │   └── instr_performance.py  
│   ├── src  
│   │   ├── configs  
│   │   ├── dao  
│   │   ├── helpers  
│   │   └── utilities  
│   ├── tests  
│   └── tmp  
├── amapitest.egg-info  
├── build  
├── dist  
├── env.sh  
├── requirements.txt  
└── setup.py
```

**additional info:**
locust 2.11.0
pytest 7.1.2
python 3.10
macOS monterey

Comment: I would add a *pytest.ini* file and add a setting called *pythonpath*. This will let you point to the location of amapitest for the duration of your tests. Here's an [example](https://github.com/jgrugru/python_template/blob/main/pytest.ini) of the file from my python template repo.

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` File in all importable folders (so it’s missing in src). You shouldn’t need to modify your pythonpath if you’re executing this from the root directory.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado they are all here, in every folder, Ive just remove all "unnecessary" content for space economy in my question)) and now I guess it was a bad idea

Comment: Oh. Yeah don’t go so far as to remove things critical to the question at hand :) could you add those back in and also provide the path where you call pytest? And is there a conftest.py anywhere? Please provide those locations and the contents.

Comment: I think the problem might just be that you’re calling pytest from inside amapitest? Or are you in the enclosing dir?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum
I dont understand how exactly I should set my pythonpath, Ive tried pythonpath = . and it does not work for me

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yes, I calling from inside amapitest

Comment: Ok can you try calling from one directory above?

Comment: And I mean please edit the question to include this additional detail in the body of the question. Don’t just comment with critical information. Please provide all of the init file locations and the exact path to the folder and to where you are calling this from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved my problem by moving "my_locustfiles" folder into root directory of project and running test from this directory.

I still dont understand why locust cant find imported methods when locust file  was located in "amapitest"

but...anyway, thanks everyone

Comment: Good that you managed to get it working, strange that you had to resort to that. If you ever want to dig deeper, you should probably try printing `sys.path` or something.

Comment: Perhaps you also need an `__init__.py` in amapitest

Answer (score 0):

Your current directory is automatically added to `sys.path` by locust, according to the documentation https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#how-to-structure-your-test-code

Try going to the parent directory and run

`locust -f amapitest/my_locustfiles/instr_performance.py`

Comment: I did it and even absolute path) it doesnt worked

Answer (score 0):

1. `print(sys.path)` to see the path that helps Python to find modules.
2. If the path is found. e.g. Let's say **"/Users/user/SomeFolder/amapitest/"**, try @Cyberwiz's comment, adding `__init__.py` file in every folder to turn folders to modules. Execute locust at **amapitest** folder

If you want to execute locust at sub-folder and module not found still happened, try Step 3.

3. Within **instr_performance.py**, append parent path like this

   ```
   sys.path.append(
       os.path.join(
           os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'
       )
   )
   ```

   You will see **'/Users/user/SomeFolder/amapitest/my_locustfiles/..'** when `print(sys.path)`, I think this workaround may helps